# Impossibility in Computability and Complexity: always ultimately due to diagonal arguments?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, computability

In Computability, if we want to prove that a problem is not recursive or not recursively enumerable, we can use e.g. reductions from other non-recursive or non-r.e. problems, Rice's theorem, Rice-Shapiro's theorem, etc. These techniques work thanks to, or are directly based on, the existence of some diagonal argument (i.e. some program $M$ behaves in the opposite way as its input program $M'$, so $M = M'$ is contradictory). In Complexity, if we want to prove that some problem *cannot* be computed in some time (regardless of any unproved claims such as e.g. $P \neq NP$), we use arguments which are, ultimately, based on some diagonal argument (e.g. the Time Hierarchy theorem proves $EXPTIME$-complete problems are not in $P$, but that theorem is also proved by using a diagonal argument).

So my question is the following. Are all important impossibility results in Computability and Complexity (actual impossibility, not impossibility up to some unproved result) *ultimately* due to some diagonal argument? That is, does all our important "impossibility knowledge" in Computability and Complexity come from the fact that programs are powerful enough to execute programs?

The only important impossibility result coming to my mind which is not ultimately due to a diagonal argument is that the Ackermann function is not primitive recursive. Am I missing other important counterexamples of this apparent "rule"?

EDIT (Nov 18): Sorry for implying that my question was particularly focusing on the diagonal argument itself, but I'm more interested on all arguments that rely on the self reference of programs (including the diagonal argument, Berry paradox, etc). For simpler languages (e.g. regular or context-free), we have "structural" impossibility arguments based on how these languages are constructed (e.g. pumping lemmas). However, for recursive or r.e. languages, most of impossibility results strongly rely on the self reference of programs. This is what I meant.

Comment: Actually the proof that the Ackerman function is not p.r. is a pretty classic application of the diagonal method!

Comment: I always thought seeing some kind of diagonal argument in the part of that proof concerning the primitive recursive operator would be a little far-fetched... Take e.g. this proof of that result: http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachumd/term/42019.pdf. Am I missing some "hidden" diagonal argument there?

Comment: Also: possible duplicate of https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6575/does-diagonalization-captures-the-essence-of-class-separation

Comment: Yes, there is a hidden diagonal argument in the proof that a function may not majorize itself, which is referred to here: http://beta.planetmath.org/SuperexponentiationIsNotElementary

Comment: Probably a bunch of results come from the pigeonhole-principle: Kolmogorov complexity comes to mind ("some strings are not compressible..."). I bet 1$ that all negative results "about a finite domain" have the PP at their root  :-D :-D

Comment: Circuit and formula complexity lower bounds are proved using entirely different techniques, like random restrictions and the switching lemma, or communication complexity via Karchmer-Wigderson games

Comment: cody: proving binary functions cannot majorize themselves does not require reasoning about programs at all, so that "diagonal" argument does not involve programs simulating themselves (contrarily to the typical computability and complexity typical diagonal arguments I was thinking about here). It's interesting.

Comment: Marzio and Sasho: those are pretty good examples indeed.

Comment: See also https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/are-there-any-proofs-the-undecidability-of-the-halting-problem-that-does-not-dep/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lower bounds in non-uniform models of computation, like boolean formulas and circuits, are proved using combinatorial arguments. Some examples are Krapchenko's method using formal complexity measures, Razborov's method of approximations for monotone circuits, the random restriction method, including random restriction + the switching lemma, and depth lower bounds using communication complexity via Karchmer-Wigderson games. You can find lecture notes on this material by [Sudan](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.841/spring09/),
 [Kopparty](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/topics-S13/), [Buss](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/CourseWeb/Math262A_2013F/), [Zwick](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~zwick/scribe-boolean.html), among others.

Comment: Personal favourite answer, I've learnt a lot, thanks. David's and Marzio's are great answers too.

Answer (score 9):

The standard comparison-model lower bound for sorting, and most cell probe model lower bounds for data structures, are unconditional (for computing within the model but you could say the same about Turing machine lower bounds) and depend on information theory rather than diagonalization.

Comment: There are also tons of information-theoretic unconditional lower bounds for various models of distributed computing and parallel computing. No diagonalisation there, either.

Answer (score 5):

A tool that can be used to prove negative/impossibility results is the *incompressibility method*:

**Theorem** (Incompressibility Theorem) Let $c$ be a positive integer. For each fixed $y$, every finite set $A$ of cardinality $m$ has at least $m(1-2^{-c})+1$ elements $X$ with $C(x \mid y) \geq \log m - c$

Some well-known applications are: a single tape Turing machine requires $O(n^2)$ steps to decide $\{ ww^R\}$; a DFA cannot recognize $a^n b^n$; impossibility of there being only finitely many primes (and estimates the size of the nth prime correctly to within a log n factor); ....

Ultimately the above theorem relies on the *Pigeon Principle* which has itself some nice direct applications; for example:

**Theorem**: if we color the points in the plane red or blue. Then for any distance $d > 0$, we can find two points at distance $d$ from each other that have the same color.

*Proof*: Pick any equilateral triangle with side equal to $d$ in the real plane. It has three vertices, so by the pigeonhole principle two of them must have the same color, and they are at distance $d$ from each other by construction.

Comment: It also gives a nice proof of the impossibility of there being only finitely many primes :). (And estimates the size of the nth prime correctly to within a log n factor.)

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow: oh yes, thanks (I added it to the answer) ... it reminds me that soon or later I should add to my blog an easy-trivial post about this easy-trivial theorem (I've never seen it anywhere): $\exists n_0$ s.t. $n \geq n_0 \land K(n) \geq \log_2(n) \Rightarrow n = a \cdot b$ :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the halting problem can be proved without using diagonalization.  (And every valid ZFC theorem has a ZFC proof that uses diagonalization...think about it.)

The proof uses the Berry paradox, and proceeds as follows:

Index all Turing machines in a reasonable manner.  Assume for the sake of contradiction that the halting problem can be solved.  Then consider this algorithm:

f(N) returns the least-indexed Turing machine X s.t. X(X) does not halt and X is not the output of any Turing machine M and input I in under N characters (i.e., M(I) outputs X --> |M| + |I| >= N).

Now, we select sufficiently large N s.t. f(N) must return a description of X that is described precisely by the computation of f(N).  If f is computable, then M=f and I=N.  For example, we could let N = one googol (10^100).

This suggests that f(N) is not a total function, because for f(10^100), there is no satisfactory output.  This contradicts the assumption that the halting problem can be solved.  Consider the following pseudocode (which is far less than 10^100 characters when expanded to true source code in C++ or even written as a Turing machine) for f:

> f(N)
>
> {
>
> for (int i = 1; ; i++)
>
> {
>
> ```
>   if (simulate DoesHalt(UTM(i,i)) == false)
>
>   {
>
>          (simulate all machines and inputs M(I) with |M|+|I|<N)
>
>          if all such inputs do not output i
>
>                  return i;
>
>   }
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Clearly, f halts on all inputs and works properly assuming that the halting the problem can be solved.  By the above, we have that the halting problem cannot be solved.

This proof does not use any form of diagonalization.  Indeed, you should glance at my question:

[Is one definition of the word paradox, "something that can be used to prove the halting problem undecidable?"](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/is-one-definition-of-the-word-paradox-something-that-can-be-used-to-prove-the)

...for some discussion of the fact that many paradoxes may be used in lieu of the liar paradox or Russell's paradox to prove that the halting problem cannot be solved.  Some of these non-diagonal-argument paradoxes include the Unexpected Hanging Paradox and (as just described) the Berry Paradox.

Comment: What does "f(N) must return a description of X that is described precisely by the computation of f(N)" mean? It looks like it means "f(N) returns X such that X is computed by f(N)", i.e. "f(N) returns X such that f(N) returns X". I'm missing some important point here... Also, note that X is undefined in your pseudocode. What is that X? Finally, is "X cannot be formalized as the output of any Turing machine M" equivalent to "X is not the output of any M"?

Comment: Regardless of whether your argument can be considered as a diagonal argument or not, it looks like it includes pretty much of what is required in any diagonal argument: in order to get a contradiction, you need to reason about a program receiving itself as an input. Ultimately, you show that there exist undecidable problems because programs are expressive enough to simulate programs, and this is critical when they simulate themselves. This is pretty much the spirit of any diagonal argument.

Comment: It means that what f(N) returns is exactly what I described in the description of how f computes functions.  Check out the Wikipedia article on the Berry paradox if this confuses you (or feel free to ask additional questions in the comments).  I meant to write "i" instead of "X" and will fix that shortly.  And yes, my wordy phrasing of "X is not the output of any M" could be simplified as you suggest.  Aside from these minor points, I hope you agree that my answer is correct.  I will address your other comment in a moment.

Comment: It is not correct to say that this argument "Includes pretty much what is required in any diagonal argument."  I'm not sure if diagonalization itself as a proof technique can be formalized mathematically; i.e., I don't know if there's a computable function that decides if a given ZFC proof uses diagonalization or not.  However, to a mathematician or computer scientist, diagonlization is a technique that is sometimes described in other ways.  Because this proof, although it is a proof by contradiction, does not proceed according to this sort of logic:  ...(cont'd in next comment)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument ...it is not a diagonalization argument.  The proof of the halting problem , like Godel's Incompleteness Theorem, could be taken as a "liar's paradox proof," but a more formal description would require use of the Cantor-like diagonalization argument in the preceding link.  I read somewhere that a mathematician named George Boolos once showed that Godel's First Incompleteness Theorem can be formalized without diagonalization, using the Berry paradox.  That approach is the inspiration for this proof that I gave.

Comment: What seems to be left unanswered that the OP was interested in, perhaps fitting for a separate question, is whether we can avoid self reference entirely.

Comment: I think I agree with the others: the essence of the Berry paradox is still the same as the essence of Cantor diagonalization. See e.g. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/21917/129, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2853/129, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/37824/129.

Comment: In a moment, I'm sure Kaveh Ghasemloo himself will descend on this thread and insist that diagonalization cannot be formalized.

Comment: I always thought of Berry paradox as a kind of diagonal argument, or more precisely, as a case of some more general argument (no-named as far as I know) the Berry paradox and the diagonal argument would be particular cases of. Regardless of whether there exists a mathematical definition distinguishing between diagonal arguments or Berry paradox, what I actually meant is the necessity of self reference: how much of our knowledge is based on self reference and not on the structure of languages itself (like e.g. pumping lemmas find the limits of simpler languages like regular and context-free)?

Comment: Anyway, the actual phrasing of my question didn't precisely show what I was actually thinking about --my fault.

Comment: I am curious as to what you mean by "self-reference."  I don't see how my argument is even self-referential.

Comment: "X(X) does not halt".

Comment: That's like saying "3*3" is self-reference because 3 is used twice in the formula.  The key to self-reference is the possibility of referring to a program in its own description...or referring to a sentence in in its own description, etc.  Merely inputting the index of a program to itself is not self-reference.  Although it may be true that i=N for one iteration of the for loop, this has no significance to the proof itself, so the argument is not self-referential.  Consider "Hofstadter's Law":  "It always takes longer than you expect, even when you take into account Hofstadter's Law."

Comment: I think there is self-reference, but it's a little buried: a key step in the proof is that if $N$ is big enough, the function $f$ must return its own code, and then this leads to a contradiction. I think the fact that the argument can be captured by a variant of Lawvere's fixed point theorem (see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/37830/4896) is evidence that it's really the same argument at heart as other self-referential proofs.

Comment: BTW I think your answer is not clearly written. Even though I know this proof, I still had trouble understanding what you wrote. The pseudocode is redundant and can be taken out, while the paragraph starting with "Now we set" is unclear and needs much more detail.

Comment: Don't be ridiculous.  I included the argument that you claim is "buried," you just need to read the argument thoroughly.  Many mathematical arguments require careful analysis; I don't think a well-trained mathematician would struggle with understanding this obviously correct argument.  (FYI:  If more individuals on this forum choose to join the chorus of voice criticizing everything I write, I know exactly what that means.tc

Comment: As much as I enjoy arguing about my own ridiculousness on the Internet, I decided to improve your answer instead. Feel free to roll back my edit if you don't like it. Notice that $X$ did not need to be a Turing machine, and this is not where the Halting problem was needed in order to make $f$ computable. Do you disagree that the fact that this argument can be rephrased to follow from Roger's fixed point theorem suggests that it's not really fundamentally different from the diagonalization proof?

Comment: I don't like it and yes I disagree.  I only glanced at your "rephrasing" for a moment but it looks like a different argument.  If you would like to post another answer of your own, that is one of the features of CStheory.se.  And of course X must be a Turing machine...this argument is about the halting problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68954/discussion-between-sasho-nikolov-and-philip-white).

Comment: @PhilipWhite: Your idea of "diagonalization" is pretty restrictive (the Wikipedia page is about **Cantor**'s diagonal argument, not about diagonalization itself).  There is a much broader meaning you can give to "diagonalization", and is related to Lavwere's fixpoint theorem, as pointed out above by Joshua Grochow.  The word "diagonal" comes from the so-called *diagonal morphism* $A\to A\times A$, which exists in any category with products.  The idea underlying diagonalization is taking a map $e:A\times A\to B$ in which the two arguments are of the same type but of different nature (...)

Comment: (...) and precomposing it with the diagonal map to get $e':A\to B$.  This map $e'$ is then used to show that all maps $B\to B$ have a fixpoint or, contrapositively, to show that $e$ cannot exist because there *is* at least one map $B\to B$ without fixpoints.  The diagonal map sends $X$ to $\langle X,X\rangle$; in your case, you are precomposing this map to the "evaluation map", obtaning $X(X)$.  It is not a matter of self-referentiality, just a matter of using the same object twice, at two different "semantic" levels.