# What are the classic papers from the recursion theoretic area of complexity theory?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lo.logic, computability, big-list, structural-complexity

Two papers I would include are:

1. D. Kozen, ["Indexing of subrecursive classes"](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/800133.804358), STOC, 1978.
2. R. Ladner, ["On the Structure of Polynomial Time Reducibility"](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/321864.321877), JACM, 1975.

Comment: this should be CW

Comment: I agree with Suresh.  Just to add: this question could probably be rephrased in such a way that it wouldn't need to be community wiki (e.g. "What should I read when starting with recursion theory?"), such that a single answer could suffice.  It's currently too open-ended.

Comment: we should use this as an example for the FAQ

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hajek, P. [Arithmetical hierarchy and complexity of computation](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(79)90046-X). Theoret. Comp. Sci. 8 (2): 227-237, 1979.  Started the study of the complexities of index sets (where their "complexities" often lie somewhere in the arithmetical hierarchy; see [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/161/can-it-be-determined-if-language-l-lies-in-np/162#162) to [another question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/161/can-it-be-determined-if-language-l-lies-in-np).)

On the study of polynomial-time degrees (buzzword="polynomial-time degree theory", for the sake of future searches) I'd say these papers are of interest (several of them are based on Ladner's technique):

- Homer, S. [Minimal degrees for polynomial reducibilities](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/23005.23009).  J. ACM 34(2):480-491, 1987.
- Schöning, U. [Minimal pairs for P](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(84)90124-5). Theoret. Comp. Sci. 31: 41-48, 1984.
- Downey, R. [Nondiamond theorems for polynomial time reducibility](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-0000(92)90032-E). Journal of Computer and System Sciences 45(3):385-195, 1992.
- Downey, R. and Fortnow, L. [Uniformly hard languages](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3975(02)00810-1). Theoret. Comp. Sci. 298(2): 303-315, 2003.
- Fenner, S., Homer, S., Prium, R. and Schaefer, M. [Hyper-polynomial hierarchies and the polynomial jump](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3975(00)00193-6). Theoret. Comp. Sci. 262: 241-256, 2001.

Probably a forward and backwards reference search will find several more papers in the same area (though it's not that big an area!).