# Lower bounds for learning in the membership query and counterexample model

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, machine-learning, lower-bounds, lg.learning, query-complexity

Dana Angluin ([1987](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0890540187900526); [pdf](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/chitti/thesis/references/learningRegSetsFromQueriesAndCounterExamples.pdf)) defines a learning model with membership queries and theory queries (counterexamples to a proposed function). She shows that a regular language that is represented by a minimal DFA of $n$ states is learnable in polynomial time (where the proposed functions are DFAs) with $O(mn^2)$ membership-queries and at most $n−1$ theory-queries ($m$ is the size of the largest counter-example provided by the tutor). Unfortunately, she does not discuss lower bounds.

We can generalize the model slightly by assuming a magical tutor that can check equality between arbitrary functions and provide counterexamples if different. Then we can ask how hard it is to learn classes bigger than regular languages. I am interested in this generalization and the original restriction to regular languages.

**Are there any known lower bounds on the number of queries in the membership and counterexample model?**

I am interested in lower bounds on the number of membership queries, theory queries, or trade-offs between the two. I am interested in lower-bounds for any class of functions, even for more complicated classes than regular languages.

If there are no lower-bounds: **Are there known bariers to proving query lower bounds in this model?**

---

#### Related questions

[Are there improvements on Dana Angluin's algorithm for learning regular sets](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/118/55)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, some lower bounds are known. For example, assuming $NP \neq coNP$, you cannot even properly learn read-thrice DNF formulas in polynomial time.  There is a whole [paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=296694) developing such hardness results using something called the "representation problem".

To answer your linked-to question: Schapire, in his [dissertation](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=136314), in addition to proving that "weak learning" = "strong learning," also improved on Angluin's bound and gave an algorithm that uses $O(n)$ equivalence queries and $O(n^2+ n \log m)$ membership queries for learning DFA.

One easy way to get lower bounds is information-theory.  You can figure out how many distinct targets there are and how many bits a query gives you, etc.  These upper bounds come close but aren't there.  There are also issues one needs to think about regarding how the "counterexamples" arrive to the learner.  A well-chosen counterexample can give away quite a lot of information.

*Update to the discussion above*: Angluin and Dohrn address the question learning with random counterexamples in a [recent paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v76/angluin17a/angluin17a.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you mind if I give your answer to my linked question on the linked question (with links back here)? Or do you plan to make a CS.SE account? I totally agree with paragraph 3, I was fooling around with demanding that the tutor give a minimal counterexample and learning seems to become much easier.

Comment: No problem! And feel free to post to the linked CS.SE question.

Comment: I read through the relevant part of Schapire's thesis (section 5.4.5) and [summarized the improvement](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/1021/55), hopefully I got the gist right. I will look more closely at the lower-bounds paper you cite later in the week :D.

Comment: Cool. I'd upvote it if I had a CS.SE account :)