# What Lecture Notes Should Everyone Read?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list

There has been several questions with the same scheme as this one:

- [What papers should everyone read](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1168/873)
- [What books should everyone read](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3253/873)
- [What are the recent TCS books whose drafts are available online](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3540/873)
- [what videos should everybody watch](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1198/873)

I was reluctant to post yet another one, but Jeff Erickson's [lecture notes on algorithms](http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/everything.pdf) changed my mind. I thought: Oh my! All these years and I haven't seen these excellent notes!

So, I thought there might be other great lecture notes, which are really worth reading. So, for each computer science subfield (*data structures, algorithms, theory of computation, computational complexity, cryptography*, etc.), recommend the superb lecture notes of your choice, and say **why** you think it excels.

One simple rule to keep it tidy: **One answer per each subfield.** (This will be a community wiki, so you can edit existing answers, and add your recommendation.)

Comment: You get my vote. If only such a list had existed back when I was a student ...

Comment: Thank you for the link to Jeff Erickson's excellent notes!

Comment: Should then this question also be community wiki?

Comment: @Dave: Yeah, I've already flagged it as CW. It requires mod attention.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once.

Answer (score 34):

### Probability Theory And Randomized Algorithms

- Lecture notes from [Ryan O'Donnell](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eodonnell/)'s course [Probability and Computing](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E15359/) is pretty neat.
- Lecture notes from [Amit Chakrabarti](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Eac)'s course [Data Stream Algorithms](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Eac/Teach/CS49-Fall11/Notes/lecnotes.pdf)

Comment: This link is now dead. Could you please fix or it will be removed?

Comment: @Dave, it seems there is no longer a link from Ryan's webpage to the course.  But I don't think removing the entry is a good idea, he might put the link back at some point. Your comment that the link is broken  is sufficient IMO.

Comment: @DaveClarke  The link is fixed. Yay!

Answer (score 26):

### Quantum computation and information

Some excellent lecture notes from this field:

- [John Preskill's lecture notes](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/people/preskill/ph229/#lecture) on Quantum Computation.

An introductory course on quantum computing. Good enough to be made into a book. I know several researchers who have a printout of these notes on their bookshelf.

- [John Watrous' lecture notes](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/quant-info/) on the Theory of Quantum Information.

An advanced course on quantum information. Some of the best lectures notes I've ever read.

- [Andrew Childs' lecture notes](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~amchilds/teaching/w08/co781.html) on Quantum Algorithms.

An advanced course on quantum algorithms. A very good resource for recent quantum algorithms. If the original paper on some quantum algorithm is hard to understand, this is where I would check next.

- [Scott Aaronson's lecture notes](http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/) on Quantum Computing Since Democritus.

I can't summarize this course in one line. Read the description on the course web page.

- [Unruh's lecture notes](http://www.cs.ut.ee/~unruh/qc11/) on Quantum Cryptography.

Includes general introduction to Quantum Computing, as well as crypto-specific topics such as Quantum Key Distribution, Quantum Commitments, Bounded Quantum Storage Model, and Quantum Zero-Knowledge.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. I always wanted to learn quantum computing, but didn't have enough time to read a book. Do you know any course devoted to **quantum cryptography**? I found one [here](http://crypto.m2ci.org/teaching/ws10/qcrypto/), but unfortunately, the notes aren't available online.

Comment: @Sadeq: Sorry, no idea.

Answer (score 25):

### Computational Complexity

There are many excellent courses on this topic. The following is merely the tip of the iceberg. To choose one, I suggest taking a look at the material covered in each course, as well as the level it is offered:

- [Introduction to Complexity Theory](http://www.eccc.uni-trier.de/static/books/Introduction_to_Complexity_Theory/) by **Oded Goldreich**. Available in two flavors: [notes for a two-semester introductory course](http://www.eccc.uni-trier.de/resources/pdf/cc2.pdf) and [notes for a single-semester course](http://www.eccc.uni-trier.de/resources/pdf/notes.pdf). You can also check Goldreich's [book on computational complexity](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/cc-book.html).
- Two different Computational Complexity courses offered at Princeton by [Sanjeev Arora](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring01/cs522/) and [Boaz Barak](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos522/). You can also check their [book on computational complexity](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/complexity/).
- [Complexity Theory](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~allender/lecture.notes/) by **Eric Allender**. Suggested by Boaz Barak at his homepage.
- [Complexity Theory](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs278/) by **Luca Trevisan**. Suggested by Boaz Barak at his homepage.
- [Advanced Complexity Theory](http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/ST03/) by **Madhu Sudan**. Suggested by Boaz Barak at his homepage.
- [Lectures in Computational Complexity](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jyc/710-book.pdf) by **Jin-Yi Cai**. Written more or less in the form of a book.
- [Approaches to the P versus NP Question and Related Complexity Questions](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~toni/Courses/PvsNP/CS2429.html) by **Toniann Pitassi**, with guest lectures by Steve Cook, Mika Goos, Joshua Grochow, David Liu, and Robert Robere. Graduate course covering many of the state-of-the-art lower bound techniques, several of which aren't well-covered (or covered at all) in other lecture notes.

Answer (score 23):

A [Theorist's Toolkit](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall02/cs597D/) by Sanjeev Arora.

I love these notes because it gives you a rather complete set of tools for attacking problems in complexity theory. For example, VC-dimension is used widely for proving lower bounds in the communication model, and these notes explains it so well and from the basics.

Answer (score 21):

### **Information Theory**

- [Anup Rao](http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/anuprao/)'s [Information Theory lecture notes](https://catalyst.uw.edu/workspace/anuprao/15415/86751) give a detailed description of the cutting-edge tools and how they are applied in recent research, including work from 2010.

Comment: This is not available anymore. Can you share it with me.

Answer (score 17):

### PCP & Hardness of Approximation

- The course offered by [Uri Feige](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~feige/pcp.html) is very good.
- Another excellent course is offered by [Luca Trevisan](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~luca/pcp/).
- Yet another course is offered by [Irit Dinur and Dana Moshkovitz](http://people.csail.mit.edu/dmoshkov/courses/pcp/index.html). This one seems more like a link farm, and has few notes.
- *Limits of approximation algorithms : PCPs and Unique Games* by [Prahladh Harsha](http://www.tcs.tifr.res.in/~prahladh/teaching/2009-10/limits/)

Comment: Which of them did you read yourself?

Answer (score 17):

### Discrete math

[Discrete Mathematics for Computer Science](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/fall10/mcs-ftl.pdf) by Lehman, Leighton, and Meyer ([older version](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall06/cos341/handouts/mathcs.pdf))

Comment: I get a 403 Forbidden error on your link.

Comment: @Derrick: The error is gone or the link is corrected.

Comment: Yes, both links work now.....

Comment: Hence the link to the older version.

Comment: Currently more up-to-date version: https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring15/mcs.pdf . It feels like finding the right link amid the many outdated mirrors has become an NP-complete problem...

Comment: @Jeffε I get a 403 Forbidden error on the first link. The link from the last comment is also password protected. However, this link might help: http://www.seas.harvard.edu/courses/cs20/MIT6_042Notes.pdf.

Comment: Currently up-to-date version: https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring17/mcs.pdf . Looks like a pattern has emerged in these links!

Answer (score 15):

### Cryptography

There are a number of excellent lecture notes on the subject, all by famous people in the field. You can choose one (or two) of the following to study; it all depends on your environment, background, and requirements:

- [Lecture Notes on Cryptography](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/users/mihir/papers/gb.html) by **Shafi Goldwasser** and **Mihir Bellare**, 2008. A series of lectures for [Cryptography and Computer Security [6.87s]](http://web.mit.edu/professional/short-programs/courses/cryptography_computer_security.html), a one week long course on cryptography taught at the MIT.
- [Advanced Topics in Cryptography](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-876j-advanced-topics-in-cryptography-spring-2003/lecture-notes/), covering more advanced topics than ordinary courses.
- [Advanced Topics in Cryptography](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/gradcrypto2/scribes.html) by **Jonathan Katz**, 2004. Covers an interesting range of topics in advanced cryptography.
  A more basic treatment can be found [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/TEACHING/crypto_F02/lectures.html).
- (Suggested by [Yasser](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/943/yasser-sobhdel)): **Yevgeniy Dodis**'s lectures on [introductory](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall08/G22.3210-001/index.html) and [advanced](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall09/G22.3220-001/index.html) cryptography.
- [Cryptography](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring10/cos433/#NOTES) by [Boaz Barak](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/1202/boaz-barak) (2010).
- [Foundations of cryptography](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~lindell/89-856/main-89-856.html) by **Yehuda Lindell**, 2010. Based on [Goldreich's famous book](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/foc-book.html).
- [Cryptography](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs276/#notes) by **Luca Trevisan**. Luca's notes cover the basic topics very nicely.
- [Advanced cryptography](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa02/cse208/) by **Daniele Micciancio**. Covers lots of advanced topics, and is specially inclined towards *secure multi-party protocols*.
- [Introduction to Cryptography](http://www.courses.fas.harvard.edu/~cs120/lectures/) by **Salil Vadhan**. Good for beginner/intermediate level.

Answer (score 15):

### Pseudorandomness

The best course on the subject is offered by [Salil Vadhan](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/cs225/). See also [this topic](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/3557#3557) for a draft of Salil's book on pseudorandomness.

Answer (score 14):

### Expander Graphs

The authoritative course is offered by [Nati Linial and Avi Wigderson](http://www.math.ias.edu/~boaz/ExpanderCourse/index.html). See [this topic](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3586/873) for more information,

Answer (score 13):

### Computational Geometry

[Lecture Notes](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2012/cmsc754/lectures.shtml) by [David Mount](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Emount/).

Answer (score 11):

### SAT

I visited a SAT course a few years ago with Professor Welzl. His lecture notes are by far the best I’ve seen throughout my entire studies.

Unfortunately, only the [2005 version](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/~emo/SmallPieces/SAT.ps) is online, including a short [list of updates](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/emo/SmallPieces/SATupdates.html).

(The fastest SAT algorithm as well as the constructive proof of the Lovász local lemma come from guys in his group.)

Answer (score 11):

### Combinatorial Optimization

- Chandra Chekuri's *[Topics in Combinatorial Optimization](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs598csc/sp2010/)*
- Michel Goemans' *[Topics in Combinatorial Optimization](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-997-topics-in-combinatorial-optimization-spring-2004/lecture-notes/)*
- Lex Schrijver's *[A Course in Combinatorial Optimization](http://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Elex/files/dict.pdf)*
- Jan Vondrak's *[Polyhedral techniques in combinatorial optimization](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Ejvondrak/CS369P.html)*

Comment: And Schrijver: http://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/dict.pdf

Comment: Jan Vondrak's notes: http://theory.stanford.edu/~jvondrak/CS369P.html

Answer (score 9):

The course "Pearls of Algorithms". [Part 3](http://www.roeglin.org/teaching/WS2010/Pearls.html): Probabilistic Analysis and Randomized Algorithms. The [lectures notes](http://www.roeglin.org/teaching/WS2010/Pearls/LectureNotes.pdf) are on [smoothed analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed_analysis). I especially like the figure 1.1 on the third page.

Answer (score 9):

**Spectral Graph Theory**

- [Spielman](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/561/) (Yale, 2009)
- [Chung](http://math.ucsd.edu/~jthughes/Math261C/Math261C.html) (UCSD, 2010)