# What online talks should everyone watch?

Tags: soft-question, big-list

In the past 4-5 years or so, partly owing to COVID, more and more talks have been uploaded to YouTube. In the same spirit as this question by Ryan Williams almost 14 years ago: [What papers should everyone read?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1168/71923), what online talks should everyone watch? Be it something that offers a completely new perspective on some problem, a talk where the speaker has electrifying energy, or a nice exposition to a new area for outsiders - what is it that no one should miss out on?

Similar to the Williams post, make sure it's one talk per post and post as many answers as you like.

Answer (score 3):

Not a technical talk, not a recent one either, but I recommend Jean-Pierre Serre's [How to write mathematics badly](https://youtu.be/tJZpdXWm4Gg?si=F-y68HLEOHUjRl0A). Besides being hilarious, it gives genuinely good advice for writing clear papers.